# Which preposition?

Tags: prepositions, expressions

Does the following work in English?

*An application for promotion applies to the subject in which the teacher is currently employed.*

That is, can you say that someone is employed in a subject? To me, it sounds utterly odd, but I have no idea how to say it in a different, more idiomatic way...

Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Why not "An application for promotion applies to the subject which the candidate (or applicant) is currently employed to teach"? –

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For some reason my comment to you has disappeared... Anyway – great suggestion! Thank you!!